# Why do I have a lot of console output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-bootstrap

I've some drop down lists in my application which I'm filling programmatically, basically it's working fine but when I'm doing some output to console, i've got a lot of repetitive output.

```
      return (
    <InputGroup className="pdInputGroup">
      <InputGroup.Text className="pdInputGroupText">{props.name}</InputGroup.Text>
      <Dropdown onSelect={handleSelect} align='start'>
        <Dropdown.Toggle className={!!props.isInvalid ? "dropdown-btn dropdownError" : "dropdown-btn"}>{props.preSelection}</Dropdown.Toggle>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
        {
          list.map((item, index) => {
              console.log("item: " + item + " index: " + index);
              return <Dropdown.Item eventKey={index}>{item}</Dropdown.Item>
          })
        }
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </InputGroup>
  );
```

The beat is in sync with receipton of information from a websocket, a heartbeat from the backend service if an application is still responsible. The websocket information is not changing anything in this case, when heartbeat tells me that the application is not responsible or heartbeat is missing, a dialog is shown. Nothing more and it has no connection in my point of view of this drop down lists.

The output looks like this:

```
item: black index: 0 DropDownInput.js:27
item: white index: 1 DropDownInput.js:27
item: yellow index: 2 DropDownInput.js:27
item: green index: 3 DropDownInput.js:27
item: black index: 0 DropDownInput.js:27
item: white index: 1 DropDownInput.js:27
item: yellow index: 2 DropDownInput.js:27
item: green index: 3 DropDownInput.js:27
item: blue index: 4 DropDownInput.js:27
item: black index: 0 DropDownInput.js:27
item: white index: 1 DropDownInput.js:27
item: yellow index: 2 DropDownInput.js:27
item: green index: 3 DropDownInput.js:27
item: black index: 0 DropDownInput.js:27
item: white index: 1 DropDownInput.js:27
item: yellow index: 2 DropDownInput.js:27
item: green index: 3 DropDownInput.js:27
item: blue index: 4 DropDownInput.js:27
```

The application doesn't seem to have a problem either, or it is not being re-rendered, but I think that the output is not normal.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of it?

Comment: From the debug output?

Comment: Yeah, include it in the post

Comment: Looks like the list size is changing few times, `item: blue index: 4 DropDownInput.js:27` is not always included in the list you are rendering. How do you populate this list?

Comment: It's a static list defined in my localization part of the code....

Comment: If you get console.logs more than what you intend to, it means that your mapping function runs more than you expect. Since I only see the return part of your code, I can only try to guess. It is possible that you use useEffect incorrectly(I don't know if you are actually using) or your state gets updated a lot more than you expected and it causes a re-render. keep in mind when you re-set your state even if state value is same, it may trigger a re-render.

Comment: Understood. I've an app state collecting receiving information from a websocket and also other sources like axios requests. So I've multiple states (useState) in this context. From this appstate I observe via useEffect some of these states but not all on a certain page. Issue is now when websocket receives something I also get an update for a different state in this context. Do you know how to debug the source of a useEffect notification?